# SQL query not returning some rows

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables as follow.

```
DATA(entity_id, crv_name, data_cnt_id)
PROCESSED_DATA(entity_id, crv_name, run_id)
RUNS(run_id, data_cnt_id)
```

Both `DATA` and `PROCESSED_DATA` have similar columns, except for the last one.
`PROCESSED_DATA` also has significantly more rows than `DATA`.

`DATA` is about old crv_name values, and `PROCESSED_DATA` contains new crv_name values.

I am trying to write a query which would return something like this, for a specific run (identified with `RUN_ID` in `PROCESSED_DATA` and `RUNS` and with `DATA_CNT_ID` in `DATA`) :

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| PROCESSED_DATA.ENTITY_ID PROCESSED_DATA.CRV_NAME DATA.CRV_NAME |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| entity123                  123_new_name           123_old_name |
| entity456                  456_new_name           456_old_name |
| entity789                  789_new_name           null         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, I can't get that last row (ie an entity which doesn't have an old crv_name, and therefore is not present in the table `DATA`) with my query below :

```
select pd.entity_id, pd.crv_name, d.crv_name
from processed_data pd
join data d on d.entity_id = pd.entity_id 
join runs r on r.run_id = pd.run_id and r.data_cnt_id = d.data_cnt_id
where r.run_id = 7
```

Could you help me to improve my query ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to pull both old and new data for a given run ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to outer join the records:

```
select pd.ntt_id, pd.crv_name, d.crv_name
from processed_data pd
left join data d on d.entity_id = pd.entity_id 
left join runs r on r.run_id = pd.run_id and r.data_cnt_id = d.data_cnt_id and r.run_id = 7;
```

In case there must be a run 7:

```
select pd.ntt_id, pd.crv_name, d.crv_name
from processed_data pd
inner join runs r on r.run_id = pd.run_id and r.run_id = 7
left join data d on d.entity_id = pd.entity_id and d.data_cnt_id = r.data_cnt_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `join` to `left join`:

```
select pd.ntt_id, pd.crv_name, d.crv_name
from processed_data pd
left join data d on d.entity_id = pd.entity_id 
join runs r on r.run_id = pd.run_id and r.data_cnt_id = m.data_cnt_id
where r.run_id = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select pd.ntt_id, pd.crv_name, d.crv_name
from processed_data pd
join data d on d.entity_id = pd.entity_id 
join runs r on r.run_id = pd.run_id and r.data_cnt_id = m.data_cnt_id
where r.run_id = 7
```

What is "m.data_cnt_id", I don't see alias like m. Maybe you need to use:

```
join runs r on r.run_id = pd.run_id and r.data_cnt_id = d.data_cnt_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want every new entity

```
select pd.ntt_id, pd.crv_name, d.crv_name
from processed_data pd
LEFT JOIN data d on d.entity_id = pd.entity_id 
RIGHT join runs r on r.run_id = pd.run_id and r.data_cnt_id = m.data_cnt_id
where r.run_id = 7
```

If you want all i.e. old and new

```
select pd.ntt_id, pd.crv_name, d.crv_name
from processed_data pd
FULL JOIN data d on d.entity_id = pd.entity_id 
RIGHT runs r on r.run_id = pd.run_id and r.data_cnt_id = m.data_cnt_id
where r.run_id = 7
```